# using jquery to retrieve the li parent title attribute

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get the li's parent title using jquery.  Below is my jQuery and html.  If i hover Sub 1, 2, or 3 i want to alert the parent's title which is "About Us"

JQUERY

```
$('a').hover(function(e) {
var whatami = $(this).parent('a').attr('title');

if(somethingnew == "About Us") {
alert(whatami);
    } 
else {
    //Do nothing
}
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="About Us">About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="Sub 1">Sub 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="Sub 2">Sub 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="Sub 3">Sub 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that works is:

```
$('ul > li > ul > li a').hover(
    function(){
        var whatami = $(this).parents('li').eq(1).find('a[title]:first').attr('title');
        if (whatami == 'About Us') {
            alert(whatami);
        }
    },
    function(){
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NF78q/).

A slight modification to the above:

```
$('ul > li > ul > li a').hover(
    function(){
        var whatami = $(this).closest('ul').prev('a').attr('title');
        if (whatami == 'About Us') {
            alert(whatami);
        }
    },
    function(){
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NF78q/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Title does not exists in parent, rather it exists in the current element which is anchor so use `$(this).attr('title')`
Try this,

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8wDPW/)

```
$('a').hover(function(e) {
var whatami = $(this).attr('title');
//alert(whatami );
if(whatami  == "About Us") {
alert(whatami);
    } 
else {
    //Do nothing
}
});​
```

Comment: if i hoverSub 1 i want it to return About Us not Sub 1

Comment: Check the demo in the updated answer and tell me if you need something else?

Comment: it alerts "About Us" when i hover about us but it needs to alert "About Us" when i hover Sub 1, Sub 2, Sub 3

Answer (score 0):

As Adil says, in your HTML title attribute belongs to , so maybe you mean the child of each li tag. If you really mean to hover over

instead of  as your question suggests, then you could do:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    var theTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title');
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var whatami = $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find('> a').attr('title');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UhCUA/1/)